# How do i fill a angular variable in Ionic after a subscribe?

Tags: angular, web-services, typescript, ionic-framework, subscribe

i'm trying to get data from a server and then show in a Ionic page, so far i can get the data with no problems and check in console.
But how do AFTER the server returns it for me?

So i have this function in a provider

```
public LoadArticle(article_id:any){
    let headers = new Headers();
    let postData:any;
    postData = {
      task: 'GetArticle',
      article_id: article_id
    }

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(postData),{ headers: headers });
  }
```

And i call it on the page i want to show

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public controller: WebservicesProvider
  ) {

  }
this.controller.LoadArticle(1).subscribe(
      data => {
        let retorno: any;
        retorno = data;
        console.log(JSON.parse(retorno._body));
        // this.navCtrl.setRoot(AbasPage);        
        // this.article_array = retorno._body.dados;

        this.articlearray.id = retorno._body.dados.id;

        this.articleLoaded = true;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.controller.endLoading();
      },
      () => {
        this.controller.endLoading();
      }
    );
```

If i write {{articlearray.id}} in the page html file i got an error

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i write {{articlearray.id}} in the page html file i got an error

You can use the safe navigation operator:

```
{{articlearray?.id}}
```

This will prevent that error and then display the data as soon as it is retrieved.

When the template is first displayed, the data is not yet retrieved, which is why you see the error. At some later point in time when the data is retrieved, Angular's change detection will be notified and the data will then appear.